# integrate multiple controllers view multiple views on one view

Tags: spring, view

I have:

1. 3 controllers (child controllers). The success view is redirected on to the parent controller url.
2. 3 form views (each one associated with each child controller).
3. 1 parent controller
4. 1 Parent form

the parent form is formed by the 3 child forms as below:

```
<form id="1" method="get" action="url of first form"> </form> 

<form id="2" method="get" action="url of second form"> </form> 

<form id="3" method="get" action="url of third form"> </form>
```

The problem is though i do nt get any errors, the parent form does not get populated with the child forms.

Can anyone please let me know what's wrong in here.